# I am getting an JSX error with this code that i am using and i cannot figure it out

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a header from a website in HTML  but i am getting a JSX error

```
<div className="container h-100">
  <div className="row h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
    <div className="col-lg-10 align-self-end">
      <h1 className="text-uppercase text-white font-weight-bold">Your Favorite Source of Free Bootstrap Themes</h1>
      <hr className="divider my-4">
    </div>
    <div className="col-lg-8 align-self-baseline">
      <p className="text-white-75 font-weight-light mb-5">Start Bootstrap can help you build better websites using the Bootstrap framework! Just download a theme and start customizing, no strings attached!</p>
      <a className="btn btn-primary btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Find Out More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line:

```
 <hr className="divider my-4">
```

It should have a self-closing `/`

As in `<hr className="divider my-4" />`

Comment: OKay so all br and hr should be selfcolosing?

Comment: @CodingOni - yes It's JSX not HTML... or `<hr></hr>` or  `<br></br>` and of course `<img />`

Comment: @CodingOni - In [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/), all void elements (`br`, `hr`, `input`, ...) must be written in the self-closing form (although I think most if not all JSX parsers tolerate it if you use something really invalid like `<br></br>`), and it's okay to write non-void elements like `div` in the self-closing form `<div/>` (it isn't in HTML, you have to write `<div></div>`).